# Is it possible to call the code command from c# to javascript function?

Tags: javascript, c#, mysql, asp.net

this is very tricky for me and I don't know how to solve this one..
i have 2 identical database table [table1,table2]
i want to transfer database item to another database and delete the data from the previous database to avoid duplication.. I used ListBox1 and ListBox2 so after I transfer the data, the next step is I want to save the changes.. 
I have insert code on C# and I'm using  on asp.net
but the problem is after I transfer the item from listbox1 to listbox2 then I click save changes button the item that i move to listbox2 will go back to listbox1 then run the c# code -_- delay? I think it will submit first before run the c# code.. which is the save code so it will save the same items :-/

that's why i come up with the idea of calling the c# code to function since the javacript always comes up first .. if you have a better idea please share

here's my tranfer item javascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#left").bind("click", function () {
                var options = $("[id*=RIghtBox] option:selected");
                for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
                    var opt = $(options[i]).clone();
                    $(options[i]).remove();
                    $("[id*=LeftBox]").append(opt);
                }
            });
            $("#right").bind("click", function () {
                var options = $("[id*=LeftBox] option:selected");
                for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
                    var opt = $(options[i]).clone();
                    $(options[i]).remove();
                    $("[id*=RIghtBox]").append(opt);
                }
            });
        });
</script>
```

here's my save C# code

```
  for (int i = LeftBox.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
       {
           //◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘ ◘ADD◘ ◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘

           string[] splits = LeftBox.Items[i].ToString().Split(new char[] { '-' });
           string id_split = splits[0];

           conn.Close();
           conn.Open();
           string str = "Select * FROM User_table_list WHERE ID='" + id_split + "'";
           SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(str, conn);
           SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
           if (!reader.Read())
           {
               reader.Close();
               SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert Into User_table_list (ID, Firstname,Middlename,Lastname,Age,Sex) Values (@ID, @FName, @MName, @LName,@Age,@Sex)", conn);
               cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = splits[0].ToUpper();
               cmd.Parameters.Add("@FName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = splits[1].ToUpper();
               cmd.Parameters.Add("@MName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = splits[2].ToUpper();
               cmd.Parameters.Add("@LName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = splits[3].ToUpper();
               cmd.Parameters.Add("@Age", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = splits[4].ToUpper();
               cmd.Parameters.Add("@Sex", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = splits[5].ToUpper();
               cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

           }
           conn.Close();


           //◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘ ◘DELETE◘ ◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘◘

           conn.Close();
           conn.Open();
           string str8 = "Select * FROM User_table_list2 WHERE ID='" + id_split + "'";
           SqlCommand com8 = new SqlCommand(str8, conn);
           SqlDataReader reader8 = com8.ExecuteReader();
           if (reader8.Read())
           {
               string id = reader8["ID"].ToString();
               reader8.Close();
               string sql9 = "Delete From [User_table_list2] Where ID='" + id + "'";
               SqlCommand cmd9 = new SqlCommand(sql9, conn);
               cmd9.ExecuteNonQuery();

               conn.Close();

           }
       }
   }
```

i hope you can help me with this thank you

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't do this all on the backend?

Comment: there are certain reasons .. i want to fully control my application that's why i need to do front and backend coding ^_^ .. example it is more easy to transfer an Item from the listbox to another listbox using javascript why? because in javascript its not submitting after you click a button.. unlike normal button that has back-end code.. it is functioning yes but it will consume more traffic because of the submit function in the future

Comment: Have you tried using AJAX yet?

Comment: yeah but i can't control it